# About Atiyah-Segal Localization Theorem

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, localization

In $K$-Theory, actually also in equivariant cohomology theory, there exists a useful theorem as known Borel-Hsiang-Atiyah-Segal Localization theorem. For $K$-Theory

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $X$ a locally compact $G$-space.
Let $\gamma $ be a conjugacy class in $G$, and $i:X^{\gamma }\longrightarrow
X$ the inclusion. Then the homomorphism $i^{\ast }:K_{G}\left( X\right)
\longrightarrow K_{G}\left( X^{\gamma }\right) $ becomes an isomorphism
$
\left( i^{\ast }\right) _{\gamma }:K_{G}\left( X\right) _{\gamma
}\longrightarrow K_{G}\left( X^{\gamma }\right) _{\gamma }
$
when localized at the prime ideal of $R\left( G\right) $ determined by $
\gamma $.

https://www.google.com.tr/books/edition/Atiyah_Singer_Index_Theorem_An_Introduct/4_JdDwAAQBAJ?hl=tr&gbpv=1&dq=Localization+theorem+Let+G+be+a+compact+Lie+group+and+X+a+locally+compact+G-space.&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover

I generalized this theorem to finite dimensional compact group (non-Lie) actions for equivariant cohomology theory.

https://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1684&context=math

Now, I'm wondering if the above theorem is true for finite dimensional compact group actions.

But, I don't know how there is a relationship between the prime ideals of the representation ring of finite dimensional compact groups and the prime ideals of the representation rings of compact Lie groups, I have no idea how difficult this question is.

Segal determined prime ideals of representation ring of a compact lie group. He said that on page one (in him article ''The representation ring of a compact Lie group'') that I confine myself to the case of a compact Lie group G: in general $R\left( G\right) =\underrightarrow{\lim }R\left( G/N\right) $, where $N$
runs through the compact normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a
compact Lie group. But he doesn't do anything other than that.

Can you give an idea about this problem? Is it a problem worth working on? Where to start?

Comment: Here's a stable doi link for the book you are citing (_Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem - An Introduction_ by Amiya Mukherjee) https://doi.org/10.1007/978-93-86279-60-6